# Netbeans 7.3.1 - Creating a folder in the project view

Tags: netbeans, project, directory

How can I create a folder to be situated on the project view/tab not on the files tab in netbeans? Because whenever I create a folder on the project view, it directly appears on the files tab and the folder is not visible on the project view itself .Please help!

Comment: For now, I am not yet capable of adding images to questions sir. What is the possible way I can do?

Comment: Host the 2 images, one of `project`, and other of `files` on external image hosting sites like tinypic.com OR some other. Pass the link here.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create a folder in a project, folder will be created successfully, but it doesn't appear as a folder icon. Instead it appears as a package icon. The same this appears as a folder in files tab.

Comment: so what can I do to make a created folder appear on the project view not on the files tab?

Comment: Maruthi Srinivas is right, you don't need to bother about folders in your `src` section. If you want to create a new folder in other locations like `class` OR `dist` OR some other, then it'll appear like a folder. Else in `src` directory, the new folder would be a package. What are you trying to achieve??? To me, it appears like an XY problem!